# BizTalk Send Port Chinese Character Issue

Tags: character-encoding, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-mapper, send-port

I am trying to write a flat file contents through send port. The content of the file contains Chinese characters. When I open the file I have written, all the Chinese character are replaced with junk values.

Please suggest if some encoding related changes to be done in send port to write the file with valid Chinese characters.

Currently I have used a Flat File Assembler pipeline with no encoding handling.

Please suggest where do I need to make changes so that the Chinese characters are written properly to the output file.

Comment: If you change the pipeline to passthrough. Can you get the xml format file with correct chinese characters?

Comment: What encoding is the original message in?  Are you sure that these Chinese characters are still intact in the message being translated into a flat file?   I would have thought that either UTF8 or UTF16 would handle it.  Please note you may need to set the character encoding on in custom pipeline in Visual Studio, as there has been a long standing (since BizTalk 2006) bug that doing it via the Administration Console does not work.